# GetComponent<Interface>.method doesnt work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, interface, implements

**I am using Unity and C#**

Hey Guys, i have a little problem:

If space is pressed i want another class to execute a method(you'll understand with the code).

First Class: everything working except of:

```
collider.GetComponent<NPCController>()?.Interact();
```

Full Method:

```
void Interact()
{
    var facingPos = new Vector3(animator.GetFloat("moveX"), animator.GetFloat("moveY"));
    var interactPos = transform.position + facingPos;

    var collider = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(interactPos, 0.2f, InteractableLayer);
    if(collider != null)
    {
        collider.GetComponent<NPCController>()?.Interact();
        Debug.Log("Interactmethod working");
    }
}
```

Other Classes I use are NPCController that implements InteractableObjects with the Method Interact():

```
public void Interact()
{
    Debug.Log("Finished the path");
}
```

and InteractableObjects interface:

```
public interface InteractableObjects 
public void Interact();
```

Full Player Controller class for everyone who wants to know:

```
using System.Collections;


public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour { public float moveSpeed; public LayerMask SolidObjectsLayer;
public float moveSpeed;
public LayerMask SolidObjectsLayer;

public LayerMask InteractableLayer;
public bool isMoving;
private Vector2 input;

private Animator animator;

private void Awake()
{
    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
}
private void Update()
{
    if(!isMoving)
    {
        //INPUT NOCHMAL ANSCHAUEN
        input.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"); //GetAxisRaw heisst, dass es immer 1 oder -1 ist.
        input.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        
        //Keine Diagonal Bewegung
        if(input.x != 0)
        {
            input.y = 0;
        }

        if(input != Vector2.zero)
        {
            animator.SetFloat("moveX", input.x);
            animator.SetFloat("moveY", input.y);

            var newPos = transform.position; //neue Position veraendert sich nach Eingabewerten.
            newPos.x += input.x;
            newPos.y += input.y;

            if(IsWalkable(newPos))//Kann er Laufen oder ist ein Object im Weg wird mit dem bool Wert isWalkable geprueft
                StartCoroutine(Move(newPos));
        }
    }
    animator.SetBool("isMoving", isMoving);

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        Interact();
        Debug.Log("KeyListener Working");
    }
}
void Interact()
{
    var facingPos = new Vector3(animator.GetFloat("moveX"), animator.GetFloat("moveY"));
    var interactPos = transform.position + facingPos;

    var collider = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(interactPos, 0.2f, InteractableLayer);
    if(collider != null)
    {
        collider.GetComponent<NPCController>()?.Interact();
        Debug.Log("Methoder Aufgerufen im InteractableObjects interface");
    }
}

IEnumerator Move(Vector3 newPos)
{
    isMoving = true;

    while((newPos - transform.position).sqrMagnitude > Mathf.Epsilon) //Wenn der Unterschied zwischen Target und AktuellPos ist gross
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, newPos, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime); //
        yield return null; //Ausfuehrung stoppen
    }
    transform.position = newPos;

    isMoving = false;
}
private bool IsWalkable(Vector3 newPos)//Kann man zu dem Vector newPos laufen?
{
    if(Physics2D.OverlapCircle(newPos, 0.2f, SolidObjectsLayer | InteractableLayer) != null)// wenn die Zielposition zum solidObjectslayer gehoert dann nicht
    {
        return false; //kann nicht laufen
    }
    return true; //kann laufen. Weg ist frei
}
```

}

Comment: I tried replacing collider.GetComponent<NPCController>()?.Interact(); with collider.GetComponent<InteractableObjects>()?.Interact(); too, but it didnt work.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `didn't work`?